# Pyspark: Compare column value with another value

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data frame:

```
+----+----+----+----+
|col0|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+----+
|   1|  21|   3|null|
|   4|   5|  23|null|
|null|   4|   5|   6|
|null|   9|  22|  42|
+----+----+----+----+
```

I tried computing the minimum of the column 'col1' and 1.5:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

cond = df['col2'] > 10
df = df.withColumn('new_col', F.when(cond, F.least(F.col('col1')*0.2, 1.5)).otherwise(F.lit(100)))
df.show()
```

But I got the following exception:

> TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 1.5 of type <class 'float'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `F.lit(1.5)` inside `F.least`, because it requires a column and does not accept a float:

```
df2 = df.withColumn('new_col', F.when(cond, F.least(F.col('col1')*0.2, F.lit(1.5))).otherwise(F.lit(100)))
```